# C++ Inheritance methods default argument value not accepted when instantiating a new object

Tags: c++, class

I have a `Regular` class. It has a `setValue` method:

```
void Regular::setValue(string id, string name, double s, int n = 0)
{
    uid = id;
    uname = name;
    sid = s;
    netcount = n;

}
```

When I run the following code

```
Regular x;
x.setValue("X01", "John Doe", 1.1);
```

It gives me an error

```
'Regular::setValue': function does not take 3 arguments
```

Should it not set the value of `netcount = 0` by default, because I didn't pass in the fourth argument?

Comment: you need to have the default value at the function declaration visible to the calling code. not necessarily at the definition of the function

Comment: Have you declared last argument as default argument in function declaration also.? setValue(string id, string name, double s, int n = 0)

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It's quite likely the calling code doesn't see the default argument.

Comment: Turns out I must not declare the last argument as default argument in the function itself, only the function declaration. Thanks! 
Is it possible to set it in the constructor instead?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should solve your problem. Only in declaration u need to specify as default argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Regular {
    string uid;
    string uname;
    double sid;
    int netcount;

public:
    void setValue(string id, string name, double s, int n = 0);
};


void Regular::setValue(string id, string name, double s, int n)
{
    uid = id;
    uname = name;
    sid = s;
    netcount = n;

}

int main()
{
    Regular x;
    x.setValue("X01", "John Doe", 1.1);
    return 0;
}
```